# Domain events that happen in the future

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-events

Should a bounded context be responsible for raising events for future dated things?

Consider the scenario where a Person has a set of Jobs. A job can be ended in the future. The domain will raise a "`JobEndScheduled`" event at the point the end date is added to the job. Should the domain also raise a "`JobEnded`" event at the time the job actually ends?

I'd love to get community feedback on this, as it must be a common problem. I can't see anything about this in any of the DDD books. I have a clear view on the answer, but would rather not influence any answers at this point.

Many Thanks...

Note: I asked a similar question last week, but I focused too much on the naming aspect rather than the actual events themselves. I hope this question is clearer!

Answer (score 2):

> Consider the scenario where a Person has a set of Jobs. A job can be ended in the future. The domain will raise a "JobEndScheduled" event at the point the end date is added to the job. Should the domain also raise a "JobEnded" event at the time the job actually ends?

That depends - is there business value derivable from documenting that the job actually ended?

In many domains, the answer is yes: the fact of something being planned is different knowledge from the fact that something happened.  Explicitly modeling those two facts makes things much easier for the rest of the domain.

Considering banking - when you look at your transaction history, often various transfers are in a "pending" state; the model *expects* that something will happen, but evidence that it *did* happen hasn't yet come in.

It will often be the case that there will be different authorities for the two events -- the scheduler and the executor (under whatever names those concepts might lurk).

> In the person/jobs example, this simply happens because time has elapsed.

Time doesn't elapse -- time in an input; see this idea by [John Carmack](http://archives.seul.org/linuxgames/Oct-1998/msg00123.html)

`If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do -- it is an important concept.`

The domain model doesn't control time -- the real world controls time, and maybe you have a mechanism for telling the domain model what the time is (more precisely, what the measurement of some reference clock).

So for instance, if we need to look at the schedule during a particular time window, we probably pass the extents of that time window as part of the query, and get back a list of scheduled items that fall within that window.

That's sort of the way that Google calendar works - you can go back and look at things that were on your calendar in the past.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the quick reply. So in the example you give, what changes the transaction from "pending" to "complete". I assume there is some stimulus from an external party. In the person/jobs example, this simply happens because time has elapsed. So in a sense, there is no explicit event or concept of "JobEnded" in the source domain. The source BC is not interested in the point a job ends, but other BCs are interested (e.g. they may need to delete the person's bank details because they are no longer allowed to hold them).

Comment: If you are sure the job end only happens because time has elapsed. than it makes sense to add the the jobEndDate information to your JobCreated event. And that event will be consumed by whoever is interested in that information.

Comment: I tend to agree with your view Mohamed. The alternative is that the source bounded context "manufactures" events that it is not interested in. This seems wrong to me, but it's just my opinion.